# OAuth Consent Screen Not Displaying Correct AppName

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I recently put my oauth consent screen in production.
It says "Verification not required
Your consent screen is being shown, but your app has not been reviewed, so your users may not see all of your information, and you will not be able to request certain OAuth scopes"

My scopes is non-sensitive

- userinfo.email
- userinfo.profile
- openid

But, when I try to use the google log in from my application, the app name display my domain name instead of my app-name. Why is that? it works in testing but not in production. Found nothing in documentation, even chatgpt couldn't help  or I might be looking at the wrong angle.

This is my first time setting up google login.

Tried resolving the issue by checking my scopes, reading the documentation, google the issue and chatting with chatgpt to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your oauth2 consent screen from google developer console and the screen you are seeing when you login

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your consent screen with your app name and logo shown, you must submit your application for review by Google. You will have to verify the domain name you are using for your client redirect URIs.

This verification seems necessary more to not have a fake name and logo than for scopes verification.